# Accept-Language header parsing without Request.UserLanguages

Tags: c#, asp.net, internationalization, asp.net-web-api2

Is there a library in C# that parses Accept-Language header without me having to use Request.UserLanguages? I'm building a service using OWIN which does not have System.Web dependency so Request.UserLanguages is not available to me.

Ideally, I'm looking for a library that also takes into account "q=" parameter also as specified in the spec - http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: can you add a using `System.Web` to your project?

Comment: How about `Microsoft.Owin.OwinRequest` or `Microsoft.Owin.HeaderDictionary` properties?